# Windows phone 8 port on cocos2d-x

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am facing a problem in porting andoird games to windows phone 8 on cocos2d-x. I have following problem in all of them

```
The BG music continues to play when I press WINDOWS button. 
It pauses when i press the button but after 5-10 seconds starts to play again
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.
Aqeel Raza

Comment: are you pausing the background music and effects in your AppDelegate?

Comment: I am pausing the background music in applicationDidEnterBackground().

Answer (score 3):

Go to cocos2dRenderer.cpp
find the Disconnect() method.
write this line in the method

```
mApp->applicationDidEnterBackground();
```

and similarly call the following line in CreateGLResources(); function

//should be applicationWillEnterForeground()

```
mApp->applicationWillEnterForeground();
```

Hope this will solve your problem.
Best of luck.